# How can we split a polygon within another polygon in Qgis?

Tags: qgis, polygon, splitting

[image: see the image]

How can I split the green area as a separate polygon fro the grey one in QGIS?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use the green polygon to punch a hole in the grey one to leave a doughnut polygon?  If so,  look for tools with names like erase or a clip that has an option to discard (rather than keep) the area of overlap.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the union tool (vector > geopprocessing tool > union). It will create two polygons with the union of the geometry from the two inputs.